# Stash list is empty, but why?

Tags: stash

I am setting a list of entries added to a favorites list. Some of it works but the set_list portion doesn't. I cannot see why its not working.

```
{exp:shortlist:view}{exp:stash:append name='dofoco-favorites'}{entry_id}|{/exp:stash:append}{/exp:shortlist:view}

{exp:stash:set_list name='favorite_list'}
    {exp:channel:entries 
         status="not closed" 
         entry_id="{exp:stash:get name='dofoco-favorites' backspace='1'}|0" 
         dynamic="no" 
         parse="inward"
    }               
           {stash:favorite_thumbs}<li>{title}</li>{/stash:favorite_thumbs}                              
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:get_list name='favorite_list'}{favorite_thumbs}{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

However, this outputs as expected:

```
{exp:stash:set name="side-navigation"}
{exp:channel:entries
     status="not closed"         
     entry_id="{exp:stash:get name='dofoco-favorites' backspace='1'}|0" 
     dynamic="no"
     parse="inward"                                         
 }
    <li><a href="{page_url}">{title}</a></li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:stash:get name="side-navigation"}
```

Comment: Does the list get created if you hard code entry ids into the channel entries tag?

Comment: Hm. Yes the list does show when I hardcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, at the point you try to use `dofoco-favorites` it doesn't exist yet. Second, without using `parse_tags="yes"` when setting the list, the enclosed channel entries tag won't get parsed and the list won't be generated in order to be captured.

I keep banging on about peeling onions, but it's a helpful metaphor when thinking about how the EE template class parses module tags: from the outwards inwards, one layer of tags with each pass.

There are various ways to subvert parse order with Stash, but in this case the `parse_tags="yes"` parameter is the simplest. Using it you can parse any enclosed tags to whatever depth you like (determined by `parse_depth="x"`).

```
{!-- capture the entry_ids, making sure the enclosed tag is fully parsed --}
{exp:stash:set name="dofoco-favorites" parse_tags="yes"}{exp:shortlist:view}{entry_id}|{/exp:shortlist:view}{/exp:stash:set}

{!-- capture the list items. We can access Stash vars like this {stash:my_var} --}
{exp:stash:set_list name="favorite_list" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:channel:entries 
         status="not closed" 
         entry_id="{stash:dofoco-favorites}0" 
         dynamic="no"
    }               
           {stash:favorite_thumbs}<li>{title}</li>{/stash:favorite_thumbs}                              
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:get_list name="favorite_list"}
    {favorite_thumbs}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `parse_tags='yes'` to your set_list parameters and removing `parse='inward'` from your channel entries tag.

Comment: Tried with no luck. The list does show when I hardcode the entry_ids.

Comment: Try adding trim="yes" to your append:dofoco-favorites list – it'll remove any extraneous spaces. I;ve found when dealing with ID's empty spaces are a killer